# Regex for a five-digit numerical String

Tags: java, regex, annotations

I'm currently trying to design a regex for a five-digit numerical String, which will be used to store the number of a flight. It's important that this number is exactly 5 numerical characters long. So far, I've come up with this, but it seems a bit flabby:

```
@NotNull
@Size(min = 5, max = 6)
@Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]{5}", message = "Please use a number with five digits")
@Column(name = "flight_number")
private String flightNumber;
```

Namely, things like specifying the minimum and maximum value, when the string must only be 5 characters long seems a bit over-the-top. Can anyone suggest improvements to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex you are using: `[0-9]{5}` is quite close to what you wish to achieve. The *problem* is that you are just saying *match 5 digits*.

What you would need to do, would be to simply add the `^` and `$` anchors to instruct the regex engine to make sure that the string is made up *entirely* of what you want. Thus, `[0-9]{5}` becomes `^[0-9]{5}$` or `^\d{5}$`.

Comment: The question is: Is it necessary? Does the annotation works by using the pattern with `matches()`, or does it use `find()`?

Comment: @npinti Thanks! Do I need the `@Size` code as well though?

Comment: @nhahtdh: I *think* it uses `find()`. That being said, in either case it should not make a difference. I cannot check at the moment.

Comment: @Zetland: No, the expression provided ensures that the match is exactly 5 characters long.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this one, it should do**

`^\d{5}$`

Comment: Thanks! Do you know a similar shorthand for `[A-Z]` only too? (i.e. letters of the alphabet only, all upper case)

Comment: @Zetland `[A-Z]` ll do , if the answer solved your problem, then please mark is answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would personally feel more comfortable taking advantage of Java's built-in math logic.  So I would do something like this:

```
int flightNumber = ...; // your code assigns this
if (flightNumber < 0 || flightNumber >= 100000) {
    logger.error("Bad input");
}
String flightNumberAsString = String.valueOf(flightNumber);
```